# Azure Functions "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error building configuration in an external startup class. System.Net.Http"

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am migrating an Azure Functions application from Runtime v3 to v4. The functions app includes Durable Functions.
Migrating the code was straight forward and I had no issues running locally. However, when I published to production, I started seeing this error:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error building configuration in an external startup class. System.Net.Http: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. System.Net.Sockets: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. Connection reset by peer.

This error happens immediately during app startup so it seems to not be an issue with the actual functions but in the initial setup connecting to Azure Storage, plus maybe something that has nothing to do with the migration from v3 to v4 and I've lost some old configuration during the update. Here what I see:

[image]

Here my host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

How can I fix it? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing the extensionBundle version in host.json worked for me:

[image]